# Problema al intentar hacer focus a input (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Existe alguna manera en que pueda hacer un focus a un input cada vez que se recargue la página? intente poner autofocus al input y funciona en navegador pero al hacerlo desde un dispositivo despues de ejecutar una función y recargar la página hace el focus pero no aparecer el selector de texto para poder usar el lector

Edita: ya intente hacerlo con `window.onload` pero no parece funcionar en dispositivos solo en web.

mi solución de momento fue colocar un onclick para hacer focus al input al dar click en cualquier parte de la página

Contexto: es un lector de codigo de barras que utilizo para generar una tabla pero al hacerlo desde el lector del dispositivo movil no hace el focus al recargar la página

```
<input class='campo_texto' id='codigo_barras' type='text' style='position: absolute;top: -300px' onchange='javascript:generar_codebar_tabla(this.value);'>
```

Comment: Habría que ver porque no funciona el evento `window.onload`, como lo implementaste? Que navegador tiene el dispositivo?

Comment: Qué no se usaba con `document` en lugar de `window`?

Answer (score 0):

Probaste usar un DOMContentLoaded?

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            document.getElementById('miInput').focus();
        });
```

Comment: si funciona en navegador perfectamente, pero a la hora de usarlo en un dispositivo android en chrome no funciona lo cuál me parece raro porque debería de funcionar